# if for any postive integer $(b-k)|(a-k^n)$ why $a=b^n?$

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b,n$ be give postive integers,and for any postive integer $k\in N^{+}(k\neq b)$, have
$$(b-k)|(a-k^n)$$
show that

$$a=b^n$$

Let $k=1,2,3$,we have
$$(b-1)|(a-1)$$
$$(b-2)|(a-2^n)$$
$$(b-3)|(a-3^n)$$
we known if $a=b^n$,it is clear right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF if $i=k-b$ Your equation implies :
$$i|(b+i)^n-a $$
for every positive integer $i$ which implies directly for every positive integer $i$:$$i|b^n-a$$ because $(b+i)^n\equiv b^n\mod i$  finally:
$$b^n-a=0 $$

Comment: It's so  Nice!+1